# SQL query optimization help please

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**TABLES (Simplified)**

Media table

```
mediaID   description       multimediaGroupID   silolID   fcsPathHigh   fcsPathLow 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1         media1            11                  6         blah          blah
2         media2            12                  6         blah          blah
```

MultimediaGroup table

```
multimediaGroupID   multimediaGroup  isPollGroup
------------------------------------------------ 
11                  You be the ref   1 
12                  Try of the week  1
```

Got this query, which I know isn't optimal. I don't like the subquery in it.

```
SELECT top 30 *
FROM media
WHERE (remoteMedia = 1) AND multimediaGroupID <> 13 AND siloID <> 16
AND siloID = 1 AND (fcsPathHigh like '%.flv' AND fcsPathLow like '%.flv')                     
AND (multimediagroupid is null or multimediagroupid not in
     (select multimediagroupid
     from multimediagroups
     where ispollgroup = 1))
ORDER BY dateUploaded DESC
```

Can anyone suggest a way to optimize it without the following subquery section:

```
and (multimediagroupid is null
or multimediagroupid not in 
     (select multimediagroupid
     from multimediagroups
     where ispollgroup = 1))
```

I'm also thinking of using WITH (NOLOCK) in it just to speed it up as it runs pretty slow sometimes and has the potential to cause a server crash.

Comment: The subquery is unlikely to be causing your problem (though I would replace with `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`). the issue looks to be  all the unsargable predicates (`LIKE` with leading wildcards, `<>`). . Look at the execution plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section that's making you uneasy can be transformed into LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 30 m.*
FROM media m
  LEFT JOIN multimediagroups g ON m.multimediagroupid = g.multimediagroupid
    AND g.ispollgroup = 1
WHERE m.remoteMedia = 1
  AND m.multimediaGroupID <> 13
  AND m.siloID <> 16
  AND m.siloID = 1
  AND (m.fcsPathHigh like '%.flv' AND m.fcsPathLow like '%.flv')                     
  AND g.multimediagroupid IS NULL
ORDER BY m.dateUploaded DESC
```

Comment: It will also returns matching group ids in left join. OP doesn't want recordrs for groups which are in multimediagroups table

Comment: This query returns rows from `media` that do *not* match those in `multimediagroups`. Note `LEFT JOIN multimediagroups g … ON … WHERE … g.multimediagroupid IS NULL`. This is an anti-join.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the subquery is causing the problem as much as the Not in being performed on the subquery. I do have a few ideas though that might help:

1. Change the subquery to return the multimediagroupid's to include. That will allow you to change the query to an in and even turn it into a join condition if you prefer. Plus, assuming this table is much smaller the "ispollgroup <> 1" condition can be handled quickly.
2. Add indexes to help improve performance on both the multimediagroups table and the media table. Don't be afraid to put multiple columns in the indexes.

For indexes, I'd add the following:

- multimediagroups: One index on ispollgroup and multimediagroupid
- media: One index on remoteMedia, multimediaGroupId, siloID (you might have to play with the column orders to optimize the query here).